# least lines of code for a 2 point decimal place python

Tags: python-3.x

What is the least amount of lines needed to convert 10+ decimal places to 2 decimal places..

I've looked at Decimal and other pieces of code but they seem to be tooo long winded and i feel like there has to be a simpler way..

I feel like i have tightened up my code gracefully and my crrent options appear to add far too much ..

here is the code im running at its current state of existence..

```
import requests
import json

cur_price_url = "http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"


def bitcoin_current_price(url):
    """
        Function to return json data from API
        “Powered by CoinDesk” http://www.coindesk.com/price/
    """
    return requests.get(url).json()


btc_price = (bitcoin_current_price(cur_price_url))

with open("btc_price.json", "w+") as jf:
    json.dump(btc_price, jf, indent=4)


def disclaimer():
    """ Returns The API Disclaimer Information as Requested.."""
    print('-' * 160)
    print("""“Powered by CoinDesk” http://www.coindesk.com/price/)""")
    print(btc_price['disclaimer'])
    print('-' * 160)


disclaimer()


def btc_cur():
    """  Displays Different Currency Rates and Information """
    print('\n USD: ' + str(btc_price['bpi']['USD']['rate']))
    print('\n EUR: ' + str(btc_price['bpi']['EUR']['rate']))
    print('\n GBP: ' + str(btc_price['bpi']['GBP']['rate']))


btc_cur()

bitcoin_usd = str(btc_price['bpi']['USD']['rate'])
bitcoin_eur = str(btc_price['bpi']['USD']['rate'])
bitcoin_gbp = str(btc_price['bpi']['USD']['rate'])

amount_input = input(str("Input Amount in USD: "))
amount = float(amount_input)
btc = 1
amount_per_add = 10
currency = bitcoin_usd
hand_charge = 5

def cur_name():
    """ Name the Currencies """
    if currency == bitcoin_usd:
        cur_prt = "USD"
    elif currency == bitcoin_gbp:
        cur_prt = "GBP"
    else:
        cur_prt = "EUR"
    return cur_prt


def convert(cur, num):
    """simple conversion between currencies"""
    e_b = btc / float(cur.replace(",", ""))
    print('\n' + str(1) + " " + str(cur_name()) + " is " + str(e_b) + " BTC")
    print(str(1) + " BTC" + " is " + str(cur) + ' ' + str(cur_name()) + '\n')

    e_b_con = e_b * num
    return e_b_con


con_rtn = convert(currency, amount)

print(str(amount) + ' ' + str(cur_name()) + " is " + str(con_rtn) + " BTC\n")


def add_x_percent(per):
    """ add x % of amount to amount """

    add_per = amount / 100 * per
    with_added = add_per + amount
    print(str(amount_per_add) + ' % of ' + str(amount) +
        ' is ' + str(add_per) + ' ' + str(cur_name()))
    print("Total Price with " + str(amount_per_add) +
        '% commission is: ' + str(with_added)  + ' ' + str(cur_name()) + '\n')
    with_hand_charge = with_added + hand_charge
    print("Total Price PLUS $" + str(hand_charge) + " Handling Charge AND " + str(amount_per_add) +
        '% commission is: ' + str(with_hand_charge)  + ' ' + str(cur_name()) + '\n')
    print("Total Profit is: " + str(add_per + hand_charge) + ' ' + str(cur_name()) + '\n')
    paypal_charge = with_hand_charge + (with_hand_charge / 100 * 5) 
    print("Price including Paypal Charge at 5%: " + str(paypal_charge) + str(cur_name()) + '\n')
    return with_added


add_x_percent(amount_per_add)
```

Comment: I feel like you could've made this question a lot more concise by not pasting all of your code. The question only appears to be about changing a number from one format to another, so why do we need to see everything?

Comment: Furthermore, the CoinBase API only appears to return the `rate` at 4 decimal points, so it doesn't even seem like you saying 'needed to convert 10+ decimal places to 2 decimal places' is correct.

Comment: my apologies henry.. i didnt know what piece of code was relevant.. admittedly i put 10+ because i didnt count the number .. what i should have said was 2+!

Answer (score 1):

I'm never really written Python, but I think you want to use the `round` function.

However, the input is a string, so you may need to convert it to a float before. This converts a string to a float:

```
float(btc_price['bpi']['USD']['rate'])
```

So rather than:

```
str(btc_price['bpi']['USD']['rate'])
```

Use:

```
str(round(float(btc_price['bpi']['USD']['rate']), 2)
```

Comment: @johnashu It helps if in your original question you say what you have tried, and what the result of those attempts were. I have updated my answer to include converting to a float before rounding. Give it a go and let me know if it works. Good luck.

Comment: Rounding doesn't technically descale the value to a given number of decimal places since the result is a floating point number.